# Make title popup appear on multiple elements at same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have images of dogs and cats on page. On hover over an image, the title pops up e.g. 'This is a cat called Tom'", or over a dog, 'This is a dog called Fido'". So far so good. What I want to do is: on hover over a cat image, the title pops up not only for that image, but for other images in the group that I specify also, e.g. all the cat images. So if there are three cat images on the page, and I hover on one of them, all three will display their respective title attributes. I imagine the solution to this lies in Javascript, JQuery, CSS, but I do not know where to start with this one. Not even sure if what I want is possible. Advice appreciated.

Comment: Please supply the code you have written so far so we can know exactly how you are attempting to develop this.

Comment: could also use 'mousedown'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can give the elements in the group a consistent `data-group` value, then use jQuery's `$.hover()` to detect the group of the currently hovered element and trigger your title text popup on other elements with the same group. Here's an example.

```js
$items = $('.item');
$items.hover(function() {
  var group = $(this).data('group');
  $("[data-group='"+group+"']").addClass('active');
},function() {
  $items.removeClass('active');
})
```

```css
* {margin:0;}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.item {
  float: left;
  max-width: 200px;
  position: relative;
}
h4 {
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  padding: .25em 0;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  display: none;
}
.active h4 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" data-group="fonz">
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
  <h4>text</h4>
</div>
<div class="item" data-group="fonz">
  <img src="http://www.star2.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/happy-days-770x470.jpg">
  <h4>text</h4>
</div>
<div class="item" data-group="cat">
  <img src="http://www.bharatint.com/img/categories/our-cat-shop-image.png">
  <h4>text</h4>
</div>
<div class="item" data-group="cat">
  <img src="https://www.royalcanin.com/~/media/Royal-Canin/Subpage-Hero-Images/150327_Hero_kit.ashx">
  <h4>text</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.